# What's the standard way of passing a return URL to a form?

Tags: forms, 10

The scenario is simple. I've constructed a `Link` object whose URL points to a form. I need a way to pass a URL to that form so that proper redirection can happen after the form is submitted.

Passing a URL (complete with route/parameters) doesn't work. For example, the following code throws a `MalformmedURLException` because `$return_url` contains a slash.

```php
Url $add_url = Url::fromRoute(add_form_route, [], [
  'query' => [
    'return_url' => $return_url->toString()
  ]
]);
```

Using `$return_url->toUriString()` prevents the error from happening, but trying to reconstruct the URI string in the form, using `Url::fromUri($uristring)`, throws an invalid route exception.

What is the standard way of passing a URL to a form in Drupal?

My preference would be doing this using POST so that the URL is not visible in the browser.

Comment: `Url $add_url = Url::fromRoute(add_form_route, [], ['query' => ['return_url' => $return_url->toString()]]);` contains two syntax errors.

Comment: The standard way to redirect after form submit would be the query key `destination`. Query parameters accept slashes, otherwise, `destination` would have the same issue as `return_url` in your code.